# Two lines from a pencil meet on a piece of paper, is there a space between them where they over lap, if so can it be?

Tags: homework-and-exercises

You have two lines, say from a pencil that meet on a piece of paper,  and overlap each other,do they really touch or if not, can you measure the distance between them?

Comment: Like do you mean can the two layers of markings be separated by some gap between them... somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Pencil lead is actually [graphite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphite) (and various clays to bind it and give it the right hardness). When you draw a line on paper you leave graphite/[graphene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphene) flakes behind plus grains of the binders. If you draw two lines across each other it is possible that some graphene flakes overlap, and the closest they could get is the layer spacing in graphite, 0.335 nanometer. But things are likely far messier since there are may binder grains that lie all jumbled up with each other. In practice there will not be a real separation between two pencil lines.

Answer (score 0):

they really touch, so there is no distance, but with most pencils you would see under a microscope very broad lines, wich overlap, but not necessarily  in al points, but so, that you could not measure a distance